# TagLostException using Nfca for an Android application

Tags: android, tags, nfc, apdu

I am currently developing an Android application (in JAVA) for NFC smartphones. I am trying to communicate to an Nfca tag but keep getting a `TagLostException` no matter the command I send via `transceive(byte[])`. The tag is well connected to the device.

Here is the important piece of code:

```
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);

    tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG); // get the tag object for the discovered tag

    nfca = NfcA.get(tag); // try and get the instance for this tag
    if(nfca == null) {
        Alert("tag","the tag is not NfcA");
    } else {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(1); //this will call handleMessage function and handle all error
            }
        }).start();
    }
}

final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    //handles the connection with the tag
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(final Message msgs) {
        // try to connect to the NfcA tag
        try {
            nfca.connect();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Alert("nfca.connect","cannot open connection ><");
        }
        Toast.makeText(NfcaActivity.this, "tag connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
};

try {
    //nfca.setTimeout(3000);
    pageBuffer = nfca.transceive(command);                                                                      
} catch(IOException e) {
    Alert("pageBuffer","cannot perform transceive "+ e.toString());
} catch(Exception e) {
    Alert("exception!", e.toString());
}
```

I am trying with the following command : `{00 CA 42 08 00}` or `{00 A4 00 00 02 3F00}` but have the same results.

Those commands are working when I am using a smart card reader and a software on my PC. The smart card is non-empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect that the card has the `IsoDep` technology available, too? If that is the case, you should connect using that. One of the commands you list looks like an ISO 7816-4 APDU to select the Master File. This is supposed to be used with ISO 14443-4 cards, which is exactly what the `IsoDep` technology represents.

Comment: Yes the card has also the IsoDep Technology available and yes i'm using ISO 7816-4 APDU commands. So am I able to use Nfca technology to connect and communicate with the card ? if yes is ISO 7816-4 the right set of command to send ? Or can I only use IsoDep to connect to it ?

Comment: For ISO 7816-4 you should use `IsoDep` (in the same way that you were using `NfcA`; simply replace that string in your code by `IsoDep`).

Comment: Indeed, my commands work with IsoDep, but I wanted to use NfcA, what protocols should i use for that if it is possible ?

Comment: NfcA is the protocol layer below IsoDep. If you were to use NfcA for your tag communication, you would have to implement ISO 14443-4 in your app (which is probably difficult to do, because of the rather strict timing requirements), because that is the protocol that your tag support. But there is no need, because Android provides what the tag supports with IsoDep.

Comment: Hi there, I'm using `IsoDep` technology but I'm getting `TagLostException` when I try to use `transceive()`. Can you give any advices?

Comment: @fuzzybee Try setting the response timeout to a higher value using [setTimeout()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/IsoDep.html#setTimeout%28int%29).